# Vue JS How to take a value from a data to another data?

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code

```
CurrencyFamily:[
                {name:'MYR',rate:'0'},
                {name:'USD',rate:'0.25'},
                {name:'SGD',rate:'0.25'}
            ],
            Currency:[
                {name=this.CurrencyFamily.name}
            ]
```

I want to take name value from CurrencyFamily to be added in Currency.. how can I do that?

Comment: This is unanswerable - you need to display some effort in trying to solve your question. if you want someone to just do the work, check out upwork

Comment: Im really sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 CurrencyFamily:[
                {name:'MYR',rate:'0'},
                {name:'USD',rate:'0.25'},
                {name:'SGD',rate:'0.25'}
            ],
            Currency:[
                {name=this.CurrencyFamily[0].name},
                {name=this.CurrencyFamily[1].name},
                {name=this.CurrencyFamily[2].name}
            ]
```